# Corrupt Gradle dependency cache after updating to Android Studio 2.3

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

I have a error while opening android studio that looks like this:

[image]

This manifested when I opened Android Studio after updating Android Studio to version 2.3.

As you can see the error message states that this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout and that I need to re-download dependencies and sync the project once the network connection is good.

How do I correct a corrupt Gradle dependency cache?  Is this error always due to a network problem?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to SO.  Your question isn't clear for people monitoring for questions like yours; especially because most of the data related to the question is in the image you uploaded.  Therefore I have heavily edited your question to include your query in text so that it is more easily discoverable.  Please edit the question some more to further clarify what you are asking and what you have tried so far.  It seems to me that you have a problem with your network connection...

Answer (score 0):

Invalid and Restart android studio, and if it still not works then restart your computer it will definitely work, The same thing happened with me, too.